# Excels Import from web not finding tables

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to import data from Yahoo Fantasy Football sites using Excel import from web. But it is not recognizing the primary data table on the page.

There is no little yellow arrow next to the table with the data.  Last year this worked fine.

Q: What is Yahoo doing to prevent this?  Or is this error because of Excel?

URL: http://football.fantasysports.yahoo.com/f1/12012/rankerresults

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on Firefox you should try the [TableTools2](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tabletools2/) addon, it's amazing.

Answer (score 0):

Well it works to an extent on Open Office Calc. So my guess would be your problem is because of Excel. Of course, I may be wrong. Since I am not part of your Fantasy Football League, I cannot see what I am supposed to see. But every link on the page shows up. Hope this helps.

*Note: If it were because of Yahoo it probably would not let you see anything.*